# direct assignation of char array vs direct assignation of integer array , C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
struct ans{
    size_t len1;
    uint8_t *buf;
    int * arr;
    size_t len2;
};
void func(ans &a){
    uint8_t b[]={"Hello"};
    std::cout<<b<<std::endl;
    int arr[]={0,1,2};
    a.len1=6;
    a.len2=3;
    a.buf=b;
    a.arr=arr;
    
}
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    
    ans a;
    func(a);
    std::cout<<a.arr[1]<<std::endl;
    std::cout << a.buf[1];
    return 0;
}
```

a.arr[1] is printing correctly but a.buf[1] is printing some gibberish.

I don't want to use dynamic memory allocation and copying the data , so i tried with direct assignment .

does direct assignment of char array to char *  work?
but i think direct assignment of int array to int *   work

Comment: Use std::array, that has a copy constructor.

Comment: At the end of `func`, the `b` is destroyed.  The `a.buf` has a dangling pointer to the destroyed `b`.  Sad panda.

Comment: Side note : using raw pointers in current C++ (for arrays) is usually a sign you're not doing the right things. Seems your teaching material is a bit outdated. Even "string.h" is a legacy "C" header file (mostly there for backward compatibility)

Comment: why it is not with the case with a.arr, because a.arr is working

Comment: a.arr is just a pointer copying that will point to the same memory. But then you end up with the bad sitation where it is unclear which of the two copies is the owner. That's also why C++ has std::unique_ptr. Again just stop using raw (owning) pointers

Comment: @sandeepkumar if you flip both prints you will find `a.arr` not working and `a.buf` working, you are invoking undefined behavior, anything can happen depending on the order to stack is rewritten, use `std::array` to get a well defined and predictable program.

Comment: Arrays are not assignable. You are assigning pointers. These pointers dangle, creating undefined behaviour.

Comment: Both assignments are invoking undefined behavior.  One of the most insidious things about undefined behavior is that sometimes it can look like it's working - but you can never rely on that being the case.

Comment: Re: "`a.arr` is working" -- just bad luck that it isn't showing any symptoms. It's not really working.

Comment: you can also try a.arr  , it will give you correct output , i have tried many times each time it is giving correct output. and I have been using these for last couple of month and it always work. But it is not the case with character array

Comment: An awful lot of scary smart people spent an awful lot of time defining and refining the C++ standard library. If you think you are going to do better after getting a couple of answers on SO, you are dangerously mistaken. Use the standard library. When you understand how it works, and why it is the way it is, you can cautiously start thinking of maybe doing something a little bit better. OTOH if you are a genius and can single-handedly revolutionize C++, you don't need SO.

Comment: " i have tried many times" You just haven't tried enough times. You can trust me on that.

Comment: undefined behavior doesn't mean the application will fail or crash, it simply means that the language doesn't cover what's going to happen in this situation, there is no guarantee `std::cout<<a.arr[1]<<std::endl;` is going to print `1`, if you insert `std::cout << "some long text to rewrite the stack\n";` before your other prints you are going to get back garbage instead of your expected `1`

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It's not a question of how many times he's tried -- it's a question of in how many different contexts he's tried it. This one program, compiled with the same compiler and with the same options, will in fact always give the same results (although the standard doesn't guarantee even this). Use a different compiler, different compiler options, or add some other code around it, and it's very likely to give different results.

Comment: @JamesKanze One context = one time.

Comment: @sandeepkumar -- *i have tried many times each time it is giving correct output.* -- "I bought a rope that is rated to hold 500 pounds.  I tied 600 pounds to the rope, but it didn't break.  I did this many times, and the rope still didn't break.  However, my friend bought the same rope, tied 600 pounds to it, and it broke immediately.  Why did it work for me but not for my friend?" -- That's what you're basically asking -- once you break the rules, you are entering undefined behavior land.

Comment: *I have been using these for last couple of month and it always work* -- Many programs have been written that run for *years* that have bugs similar to yours but have not crashed *yet*.  But as soon as that program is rebuilt using a new compiler, or with different compiler options, or even run on new hardware, then the program falls apart, crashes, gives weird results -- in general doesn't work properly.  So you trying for months with the same program doesn't mean anything.  Others with much more C++ experience are telling you the issues with your code, so do not ignore them.

Comment: Handy reading: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/4581301)

Comment: Here is your code with a couple extra diagnostics turned on: https://godbolt.org/z/cosYMvxa6 . Here is your code with those same extra diagnostics AND the missing include statement: https://godbolt.org/z/8rW9fhxzs The Address Sanitizer turned on as part of `-fsanitize=address,undefined` Picks off the stack-use-after-return other commenters have warned of. Sanitizers are very handy for catching mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the assignments of the array to a pointer are working, up to a point. Both do the same thing: they assign the address of the first element of the array to the pointer. The problem is that once you leave to function, the array no longer exists, so the pointers point to nowhere. Using them after returning from the function is undefined behavior, and if one seems to work -- seeming to work is one possible result of undefined behavior.

If the arrays you're trying to capture are in the function, and you want to access them later, you'll need either some sort of deep copy (which you'd get from `std::array`), or allocate the arrays in some way that their lifetime extends beyond the end of the function -- either dynamically, or by making them static. If the arrays are small, and always have the same length, `std::array` is probably the way to go. If you can use the same array each time the function is called, then declaring the arrays `static` in the function would work. In the most general case, however, you really need to go with dynamic allocation, in the form of `std::vector`.

And note that with `std::array` or `std::vector`, you don't need the `len` fields.